# How do i get jQuery to work with me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on an accordion. Watching some dude on youtube do it and writing everything as he does, it works on his video but not on my pc.

Here is what I do (yes, I did declare the HTML in the begining and yes i have opened and closed the `<head>` properly).

```
<title> Въпроси - TheZone </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="thezonesh.css">
<script src="js\jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom\jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function()
{
$("dd").hide();

});
</script>
```

//---Some menus and headers---

```
<div id="accordion">
<dl>
<dt><h3>Какво реално получавам , когато подпиша договор за ТВ и Интернет с вас ?
</h3></dt>
<dd>

<ul>
<li><p> Повечето договори за интернет включват безплатен рутер с тях. (Всеки договор за интернет за скорост над
    30Mbps). Това означава , че ние ви даваме рутер за ползвне за срока на договора , който е настроен от нас.
    Следователно - от Ваша страна не се очаква никаква настройка. За улеснение на нашите клиенти, ще ви дадем име
    и парола на мрежата за рутера по ваш избор. В случай , че сте подписали договор включващ Fiber (оптичен интернет и ТВ)
    вие получавате ONT устройство за ползване до края на договора. То се монтира на входа на жилището (от вътрешна или външна страна
    , по ваше желание). С помощта на това устройство , се разделя сигналът на ТВ и Интернет от един оптичен кабел ,
    за да се захрани вътрешната мрежа (в самото жилище) до съответните устройства. Също така , за приемане на цифров сигнал(в случай , че
    нямате телевизор с вграден тунер) ние ви даваме цифров приемник според вашата тарифа (Start TV , Comfort TV - SD приемник. Max TV - HD приемник)
    с помощта на който вие ще можете да гледате пълния набор от канали за вашия тарифен план. Всичко това вие получавате БЕЗПЛАТНО !</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

So I have no idea how to work with jQuery i just watch videos and hope to get experience with time but I'm doing everything the exact same way as he is. In his video when he saved the file like this the `<dd>` was hidden, it was not shown, while this isn't working with me.

I'm guessing the issue is with the declaration of the jQuery files that are responsible for the action . but I have no idea which one im supposed to get.

Comment: are you sure you have jquery in the specified folder?

Comment: checked 5 times  , tried both \ and / for separators , checked name , checked directory , in the end i copy pasted it. STILL not working. ON chrome , does this tell u anything ?

Comment: [Open your console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and take a look at what the error says. For starts, if you see something like `$ is not defined` then there is a problem with the location of your jQuery script file. Let us know what it says.

Comment: Does the file "js\jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom\jquery-ui.js" actually exist? Or did you just add a link withtout putting the JavaScript file in that location? Do you have the jQuery core file?

Comment: You don't have jQuery on the page.

Comment: I have a main folder named Experiment in there i keep EVERYTHING i need for the site. in there i have CSS JS images folders. the the JS i add the JS , so yes i checked it 5 times. here is the console error report

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Manual.html:10 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
file:///D:/Experiment/empty.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

im not sure how can i tell which one is the CORE  file ,,,  i have the jquery-ui and jquery-ui.min

Comment: $ not defined. Means jquery has not been added. Maybe post a screenshot of the console errors. Else, use jquery CDN as answered by @Howard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - make sure that you include jQuery along with jQuery UI (jQuery must be included first)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

These have to be included in your document prior to calling any functions that use them.  I prefer to include libraries in the `<head>` of the document.

After you get your layout the way you want it - you have to tell jQuery that the `accordion` div is an accordion, like this:

```
<script>
    $("#accordion").accordion();
</script>
```

This should be located right before the closing of the body element `</body>`

Here's a full example for you:

```js
$("#accordion").accordion();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Повечето договори за интернет включват безплатен рутер с тях. (Всеки договор за интернет за скорост над
            30Mbps). 
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Повечето договори за интернет включват безплатен рутер с тях. (Всеки договор за интернет за скорост над
            30Mbps). Това означава , че ние ви даваме рутер за ползвне за срока на договора , който е настроен от нас.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think it would also be helpful to you do go through the examples here:  https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

These examples will show you different functionality.  Here's an example that changes the default accordion functionality and allows you to collapse all sections:

```js
$("#accordion").accordion({ 
  collapsible: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Повечето договори за интернет включват безплатен рутер с тях. (Всеки договор за интернет за скорост над
            30Mbps).
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Повечето договори за интернет включват безплатен рутер с тях. (Всеки договор за интернет за скорост над
            30Mbps). Това означава , че ние ви даваме рутер за ползвне за срока на договора , който е настроен от нас.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Thank you sire ! It actually did disappear , the section i wanted at least. So in the end what i did wrong was - i did not tell j Query that the div is an accordion and i didn't  declare j Query in the first place right ?

Comment: Yes, those two things are what you needed.  Check out the examples on jquery-ui.com, you can probably learn a lot more from them.  Also - feel free to come back here and ask any questions you may have :-)

Comment: Thanks bruh ! Is there any way I can like , evaluate you or more like praise you for the help u gave me ? (new to stackoverflow as well) apart from upvoting the answer (which i cant do since im not lv 15)

Comment: Not really any other way here, voting is enough of a thanks for me :-)

Comment: Unnecessary feedback : That source code for the Accordion you gave me. Its a gem !!! I got my accordion to work and look so crisp ahhh  
_༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ GIVES APPRITIATION ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ_
Point being thank you very very very much . some times some things dont work for some reason and looking for that reason instead of trying something else is faster , but wont teach you where you went wrong... point being thank you again , im really happy you helped me and im kind of getting the basic idea of jQuery ;)

PS: Any idea how do I make it so that the first Header isnt automatically opened on pageload ?

Comment: Excellent!  I'm glad it worked out well for you!  That's what we are here for, and I'm glad I was able to help you out!